# What does "if Allah had a son" mean? Does it indicate that Allah can have a son?

Tags: quran, tafseer, christianity

> Say: "If (Allah) Most Gracious had a son, I would be the first to worship."
>
> [Quran as-Zukhruf, verse 83](http://www.islamawakened.com/quran/43/81)

**Question:** What does "if Allah had a son" mean?
*It seems its possible to interpret this and saying that Allah can have a son, because of the wordings "if Allah had a son". Please clarify what it means, with some tafsir or other related clarification.*

Comment: http://www.recitequran.com/tafsir/en.ibn-kathir/43:81 It would have taken you less time to Google it rather than ask  the questione here, shows lack of effort

Answer (score 4):

[Malik's](http://www.alim.org/library/quran/ayah/compare/43/81/on-the-day-of-judgement-believers-will-have-no-fear-or-regret,-they-will-be-warded-paradise-and-made-happy-and-o-prophet-tell-the-christians,-if-allah-had-a-son,-i-would-have-been-the-first-one-to-worship-him) translation of the verse is:

> O Prophet tell the **Christians**: "If the Compassionate (Allah) had a son, I would be the first to worship him."

Therefore it is directed to the Christians.

From [Tafsir at-Tabari](https://muflihun.com/43/81?tid=8123&tafid=8165&wrd=1&triid=63):

> "If the Most Beneficent (Allah) had a son (or children as you pretend), then I am the first of Allah's worshippers **[who deny and refute this claim of yours (and the first to believe in Allah Alone and testify that He has no children)].**"

From [Tafsir al-Maududi](https://muflihun.com/43/81?tid=8123&tafid=8165&wrd=1&triid=63):

> Say: "If the Merciful One had a son, I would have been the first one to worship him."
>
> It means: My rejection of somebody’s being God’s offspring and my refusal to worship those whom you regard as His offspring is not due to any stubbornness and obduracy. My reason for the refusal is only this that God has no son or daughter, and your such beliefs are against the reality; otherwise I am such a faithful servant of my Lord that if at all the reality had been the same as you state I would have submitted myself in worship before you.

It is saying that Muhammad to say to the Christians that **if Allah had a son (which you (Christians) pretend He does) then Muhammad will say to them that He is the first person to say that what they believe is false.**

And Allah knows best.

Comment: I think tafsir maududi explains it excellent

Comment: The Tafsir al-Maududi is so pleasant and clear to read

Comment: Those tafsirs seem to go directly against what the verse says and implicates...The verse strongly suggests that if Allah had a son, then he would still worship Allah...